# overriding a method in R, using NextMethod

Tags: oop, r

how dows this work in R...

I am using a package (zoo 1.6-4) that defines a S3 class for time series sets. 
I am writing a derived class where I want to override a few methods and can't get past this one:`[.zoo`!

in my derived class rows are indexed by timestamp, like in zoo, but differently from zoo, I allow only `POSIXct` values in the index.  my users will be selecting columns all of the time, while slicing series only occasionally so I want to offer `obj[name]` instead of `obj[, name]`.

my objects have class `c("delftfews", "zoo")`.

but...

how do I override a method?

I tried this:

```
"[.delftfews" <- function(x, i, j, drop=TRUE, ...) {
  if (missing(i)) return(NextMethod())
  if (all(class(i) == "character") && missing(j)) {
    return(NextMethod('[', x=x, i=1:NROW(x), j=i, drop=drop, ...))
  }
  NextMethod()
}
```

but I get this error: `Error in rval[i, j, drop = drop., ...] : incorrect number of dimensions`.

I have solved by editing the source from zoo: I removed those `...`, but I don't get why that works.  anybody can explain what is going on here?

Comment: To debug, use `debug(zoo:::"[.zoo")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that with the above definition of `[.delftfews` this code:

```
library(zoo)
z <- structure(zoo(cbind(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)), class = c("delftfews", "zoo"))
z["a"]
# generates this call: `[.zoo`(x = 1:6, i = 1:3, j = "a", drop = TRUE, z, "a")
```

Your code does work as is if you write the call like this:

```
z[j = "a"]
# generates this call: `[.zoo`(x = z, j = "a")
```

I think what you want is to change the relevant line in `[.delftfews` to this:

```
return(NextMethod(.Generic, object = x, i = 1:NROW(x), drop = drop))
# z["a"] now generates this call: `[.zoo`(x = z, i = 1:3, j = "a", drop = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I understood from your -working- example: when invoking NextMethod, all parameters already specified stay specified in the order and form (named/unnamed) they were received.  I can't override unnamed parameters and I don't need to repeat the `...`.  I can override or fill in named parameters if I wish to do so.  (also interesting the behaviour of `drop`: to have `[.zoo` use the default defined in `[.delftfews`, I must pass it as `drop=drop`).  (`object` is named `object` even if one names it differently!).  what is the role of that `.Generic`?

Comment: p.s.: the shortest still working version was: `NextMethod(i=1:NROW(x), drop=drop)`

Comment: .Generic equals `"["` in this case.  `?NextMethod` mentions it and a few other similar ones.  BTW, you might want to use `i = seq_len(NROW(x))` if its possible for `x` to have zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

A point of clarification: allowing only POSIXct index values *does not* allow indexing columns by name only.  I'm not sure how you arrived at that conclusion.

You're overriding zoo correctly, but I think you misunderstand `NextMethod`.  The error is caused by `if (missing(i)) return(NextMethod())`, which calls `[.zoo` if `i` is missing, but `[.zoo` requires `i` because zoo's internal data structure is a matrix.  Something like this should work:

```
if (missing(i)) i <- 1:NROW(x)
```

though I'm not sure if you have to explicitly pass this new `i` to `NextMethod`...

You may be interested in the `xts` package, if you haven't already taken a look at it.

Comment: I'm reserving POSIXct as type for indexing rows and character as type for indexing columns.  seems to me a clear-cut distinction.  why do you say the contrary?

Comment: as far as I can see, `[.zoo` does not require `i` nor `j`.  the code for `[.zoo` already contains the same `if (missing(i)) i <- 1:NROW(x)`.  if `i` is missing or is `NULL`, the whole column is returned.  try something like `TS[, name]`.  looks awkward, but works.

Comment: about `NextMethod`, more than "misunderstanding", I'm sure I'm not understanding its logic nor implementation nor suggested usage and my question is exactly about this.  I have a fair though rusty theoretical compilers knowledge so I trust I can follow an explanation.